# nested array list length returning all the list length

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i have a complex json list in my flutter and i want to return the length of array object's nested list. but it is returning all the lists length.

my json list

```
{
    "clients": [
           {
            "id": 58,
            "name": "mmkmkmk",
            "address": "mmakaka",
            "tin_no": "9887665",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "2022-10-04T18:32:52.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-10-04T18:32:52.000000Z",
            "phones": [
                {
                    "id": 43,
                    "client_id": "58",
                    "supplier_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "phone_number": "987098709",
                    "email": "mmk@asd.fv",
                    "model": "Client",
                    "category": "Sales",
                    "created_at": "2022-10-04T18:32:52.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-10-04T18:32:52.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Konka33",
        "address": "bole33",
        "tin_no": "41231343",
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z",
        "phones": [
            {
                "id": 44,
                "client_id": "59",
                "supplier_id": null,
                "company_id": null,
                "phone_number": "412313421",
                "email": "i34@mail.com",
                "model": "Client",
                "category": "Manager",
                "created_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 45,
                "client_id": "59",
                "supplier_id": null,
                "company_id": null,
                "phone_number": "-1780132721",
                "email": "b34@bmail.com",
                "model": "Client",
                "category": "Sales",
                "created_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-10-04T18:33:54.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I want to display the selected index `phones` length.

I'm trying to do that by doing `datasList[index].phones!.length` but it's returning all of the length of the `phones` object from all `clients` `phones` object. not the index i wanted. how can i display the selected `phones` length?

client model

```
class Client {
  List<Clients>? clients;

  Client({required this.clients});

  Client.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['clients'] != null) {
      clients = <Clients>[];
      json['clients'].forEach((v) {
        clients?.add(new Clients.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.clients != null) {
      data['clients'] = this.clients!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Clients {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? address;
  int? tinNo;
  int? status;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<Phones>? phones;

  Clients(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.address,
      this.tinNo,
      this.status,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.phones});

  Clients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    address = json['address'];
    tinNo = json['tin_no'];
    status = json['status'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    if (json['phones'] != null) {
      phones = <Phones>[];
      json['phones'].forEach((v) {
        phones!.add(new Phones.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['tin_no'] = this.tinNo;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    if (this.phones != null) {
      data['phones'] = this.phones!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Phones {
  int? id;
  int? clientId;
  Null? supplierId;
  Null? companyId;
  int? phoneNumber;
  String? email;
  String? model;
  String? category;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Phones(
      {this.id,
      this.clientId,
      this.supplierId,
      this.companyId,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.email,
      this.model,
      this.category,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Phones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    clientId = json['client_id'];
    supplierId = json['supplier_id'];
    companyId = json['company_id'];
    phoneNumber = json['phone_number'];
    email = json['email'];
    model = json['model'];
    category = json['category'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['client_id'] = this.clientId;
    data['supplier_id'] = this.supplierId;
    data['company_id'] = this.companyId;
    data['phone_number'] = this.phoneNumber;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include your class model?

Comment: you wanted to print/log the data? so you will have an idea to get the object inside on the list?

Comment: @eamirho3ein i added the model

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes but i only need the array data from the selected list

Comment: you want Phones length? but it return what?

Comment: @eamirho3ein all lengths of all phones found in clients list

Comment: could you add the part you where using datasList[index].phones!.length?